# Hibernate criteria query is returning me stale results

Tags: hibernate, pagination, criteria, hsqldb

I have a simple table ApplicationLog in Hsqldb 1.8.0

A seperate client inserts data into this table.

I am querying this table from another java client.
I find that the criteria query count is not correct if this querying java client is left running.(i.e if the inserts happen via the other client , when I query I dont see those results - the other client does commit and I can view the inserted statements from a sql client - only my hsql client has problems viewing the new data)

If I close the client and restart it the data returned.

Here is my code for querying:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateConfigurer.getFactory();

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(
ApplicationLog.class).setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);

if(keys != null) 
{
int size = keys.length;

Long[] allKeys = new Long[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
allKeys[i] = new Long(keys[i]);
}

criteria.add(
Restrictions.in(
"applicationLogItemKey", allKeys));
}

if((from != null) && (to != null)) 
{
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge(
"logTime", from));
criteria.add(Restrictions.le(
"logTime", to));
} else {

if(from != null) {
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge(
"logTime", from));
} else if(to != null) {
criteria.add(Restrictions.le(
"logTime", to));
}

}

criteria.setFirstResult(startNumber);
criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("logTime"));

List applicationLogs = criteria.list();

session.close();
return applicationLogs;
```

I tried different cache modes thinking I am only hitting the cache.
I also tried evicting the class in question. But nothing helps. I see only stale data and not the newly inserted data unless I restart my client.

Can someone help please.

Comment: What are you passing in as from and to? are they same during your run of the client?

Answer (score 0):

Use `session.flush()`. Flushing the Session gets the data that is currently in the session synchronized with what is in the database.

One small concern:  There are too many unknowns i.e. 'to', 'from' and 'startNumber' etc. Check if they are proper.

Comment: I do use the session.flush at the place where I am inserting new records. The above code just reads - so is a session.flush needed even when reading?

Comment: Nopes, you need not to do that! sorry!